# JSON object extract from big query database using app script

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I have a big query table that has a JSON object as one of the field in the table. How can I extract the data from the JSON object using app script. The object itself is nested. It looks like this

```
{
    "uid": "124551",
    "subjects": [
        {
            "tid": 37,
            "title": "Algebra",
            "html_id": "algebra",
            "selected": true
        },
        {
            "tid": 214853,
            "title": "Trigonometry",
            "html_id": "trigonometry",
            "selected": true
        },
        {
            "tid": 38,
            "title": "Geometry",
            "html_id": "geometry",
            "selected": true
        }
    ],
    "cellphone": "09178854579",
    "educations": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "schoolname": "University of the Philippines - Los Baños",
            "degree": "BS Mathematics",
            "major": "Mathematics",
            "eduFrom": "2009-05-31T16:00:00.000Z",
            "eduTo": "2013-04-26T16:00:00.000Z",
            "eduFromTs": 1243785600,
            "eduToTs": 1366992000
        }
    ],
    "info": {
        "os": "Windows",
        "internet": "ADSL",
        "browser": "Chrome",
        "network": "Wireless",
        "speed": "",
        "timezone": "Asia/Hong_Kong"
    }
}
```

I want to extract all school names from education field. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Working with JSON objects is similar to working with XML, except that parsing or encoding a JSON object is much easier.

Once this string is retrieved, simply call JSON.parse() on the string to get a native object representation.

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
Browser.msgBox(data.info.os);
```

Other sample code is at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery#run_query